# Why is the native NodeJS test runner TAP output truncated?

Tags: node.js, test-runner

NodeJS now comes with a builtin native test runner enabled by the `--test` flag.

```bash
node --test
```

Which sends TAP version 13 output to `stdout`.

However, it is incomplete and contains `...` in multiple places to signify that the output is truncated.

```
not ok 1 - misc
   ---
   duration_ms: 5.883684
   failureType: 'subtestsFailed'
   error: '1 subtest failed'
   code: 'ERR_TEST_FAILURE'
   ...
```

I thought that it might be due to it being output to the terminal, so I tried redirecting it to a file.

```bash
node --test > temp.tap
```

Which produced the exact same result.

I also tried to use the `run` function from the `node:test` module, and apart from having to specify all of my test files manually, because it wasn't able to locate them automatically like the console command does, it sends the same exact truncated output to stdout.

What is the cause of this and is there any solution I might try?

Answer (score 0):

The output is actually, **not truncated**.

According to the TAP specification, the three dots `...` is actually part of YAML blocks/ YAML diagnostics:

[TAP 13](https://testanything.org/tap-version-13-specification.html)

> **YAML blocks**
>
> If the test line is immediately followed by an indented block beginning with /^\s+---/ and ending with /^\s+.../ that block will be interpreted as an inline YAML document. The YAML encodes a data structure that provides more detailed information about the preceding test...

[TAP 14](https://testanything.org/tap-version-14-specification.html)

> **YAML Diagnostics**
>
> If a Test Point is followed by a 2-space indented block beginning with the line  `— and ending with the line …`, separated from the Test Point only by comments or whitespace, then the block of lines between these markers will be interpreted as an inline YAML Diagnostic document according to version 1.2 of the YAML specification...

Comment: I know that it is valid yaml, but crucial information is missing after those dots, like the expected and actual values and even the error message. The "test:fail" event of the run function also contains those "..." and is also truncated, but it contains more information. However, if you just take the output of "node --test" and pass it to tap-parser what you will get is a result that has almost 0 actually valuable information. You will know that a test has failed, but not which one and why.

Comment: IC. I don't know if its related to your case, but right now there's a bit different behavior when you're running test with the `---test` flag or without the `--test`  flag. Some diagnostic messages are actually omitted or not reported when `--test` is used. The issue has been discussed multiple times in node's repository, for example: [nodejs/node/issues/45833](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45833), [nodejs/node/issues/45910](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45910) [nodejs/node/issues/45911](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/45911)

Comment: Those are irrelevant, but still interesting to know, thus an upvote :) Yes, I was using the "--test" flag, but hence switched to the programmatic use of the `import { run } from "node:test";` function instead.